# ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor (DBD ERROR: OCIServerAttach)

Tags: oracle10g, windows-server-2003, virtualbox

I created a Windows 2003 R2 Virtual Machine running on VirtualBox and I installed Oracle (10201_database_win32).

I assigned a static IP on the Virtual Ethernet too.

Everything worked great right after installation.

I listed(`lsnrctl services`) the services the listener knew right after installation and the result was:

```
LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on 15-JUL-2010 23:02
:19

Copyright (c) 1991, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:39 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "orclXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1002 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: ORACLE10GVM, pid: 760>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1035))
Service "orcl_XPT" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:39 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

So I restarted and nothing was working anymore. I executed the same command and here is what I got:

```
LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on 16-JUL-2010 21:29:20

Copyright (c) 1991, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

I unistalled/reinstalled 5-6 times and nothing. So I do not quite get what's the problem.
The services are all started and running as far as I checked.

I am out of ideas and time here.

Any suggestions? I checked numerous forums etc with no concrete answer or solution.

I hope someone can help!

Here is the listener.log file:

```
TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on 15-JUL-2010 21:56:27

Copyright (c) 1991, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

System parameter file is C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Log messages written to C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\log\listener.log
Trace information written to C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\trace\listener.trc
Trace level is currently 0

Started with pid=372
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))
Listener completed notification to CRS on start

TIMESTAMP * CONNECT DATA [* PROTOCOL INFO] * EVENT [* SID] * RETURN CODE
15-JUL-2010 21:56:30 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=Administrator))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:56:35 * service_register * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:57:15 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:57:17 * service_died * orcl * 12537
15-JUL-2010 21:57:19 * service_register * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:57:22 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:57:25 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:57:46 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:57:55 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:58:14 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:58:17 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:58:23 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:58:26 * service_died * orcl * 12537
15-JUL-2010 21:58:28 * service_register * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:58:33 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:58:36 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:58:39 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:58:45 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:58:56 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=))(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1037)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:58:57 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:58:57 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=))(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1038)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:58:57 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=))(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1039)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:58:57 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=))(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1040)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:59:00 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:59:06 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 21:59:39 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:00:12 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:00:20 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=))(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1046)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:00:21 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:00:23 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin\emagent.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1047)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:00:25 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin\emagent.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1048)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:00:26 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1050)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:00:28 * ping * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:00:28 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:00:38 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1054)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:00:39 * log_status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:00:42 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:00:45 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:01:08 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1068)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:01:18 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:01:51 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:02:04 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=services)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521))))(VERSION=169869568)) * services * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:02:05 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:05:28 * ping * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:05:28 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:05:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1102)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:07:01 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1111)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:07:02 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1112)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:07:03 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1113)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:07:03 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:07:55 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:08:58 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:10:28 * ping * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:10:28 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:10:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1137)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:11:31 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1141)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:12:31 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:12:56 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1150)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:15:28 * ping * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:15:28 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:15:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1170)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:16:07 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1173)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:16:53 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:17:04 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=services)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521))))(VERSION=169869568)) * services * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:17:05 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:19:02 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:20:20 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:20:28 * ping * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:20:28 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:20:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1199)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:21:14 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:25:28 * ping * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:25:28 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:25:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1227)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:26:33 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:27:01 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=))(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1236)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:27:03 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:30:28 * ping * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:30:28 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:30:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1259)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:31:07 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1262)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:31:09 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:32:05 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=services)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521))))(VERSION=169869568)) * services * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:32:06 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:35:22 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:35:28 * ping * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:35:28 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:35:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1288)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:40:28 * ping * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:40:28 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:40:34 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:40:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1316)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:42:56 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1329)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:44:56 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:45:28 * ping * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:45:29 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:45:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1345)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:46:08 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1348)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:46:08 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:47:05 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=services)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521))))(VERSION=169869568)) * services * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:47:06 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:50:20 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:50:28 * ping * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:50:28 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:50:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1376)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:55:28 * ping * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:55:28 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:55:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1404)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:55:39 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:58:32 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=))(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1423)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:58:32 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=))(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1424)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:58:33 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:58:36 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:58:37 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=))(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1425)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:58:37 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=))(SID=orcl)(SERVER=DEDICATED)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1426)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:58:37 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=))(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1427)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:58:39 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:59:09 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 22:59:43 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 23:00:26 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1439)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 23:00:29 * ping * 0
15-JUL-2010 23:00:29 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 23:00:37 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1445)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 23:01:07 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 23:01:08 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\perl\5.8.3\bin\MSWin32-x86-multi-thread\perl.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=SYSTEM))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1448)) * establish * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 23:02:04 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=services)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521))))(VERSION=169869568)) * services * 0
15-JUL-2010 23:02:05 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=SYSTEM))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))(VERSION=169869568)) * status * 0
15-JUL-2010 23:02:20 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=)(USER=Administrator))(COMMAND=services)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=169869568)) * services * 0
15-JUL-2010 23:03:07 * service_update * orcl * 0
15-JUL-2010 23:03:07 * service_died * orcl * 12547
TNS-12547: TNS:lost contact
15-JUL-2010 23:03:08 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(CID=(PROGRAM=C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin\emagent.exe)(HOST=ORACLE10GVM)(USER=OraUser))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1459)) * establish * orcl * 12505
TNS-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on 15-JUL-2010 23:07:58

Copyright (c) 1991, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

System parameter file is C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Log messages written to C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\log\listener.log
Trace information written to C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\trace\listener.trc
Trace level is currently 0

Started with pid=1552
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oracle10gvm)(PORT=1521)))
Listener completed notification to CRS on start

TIMESTAMP * CONNECT DATA [* PROTOCOL INFO] * EVENT [* SID] * RETURN CODE
15-JUL-2010 23:08:17 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=))(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1030)) * establish * orcl * 12514
TNS-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
15-JUL-2010 23:08:18 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=))(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.56.101)(PORT=1032)) * establish * orcl * 12514
TNS-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have some vague recollections of Oracle databases needing a bit of fiddling when you reboot for the first time after installing the database.  However, you haven't given us enough information to work on.  To start with:

- What code are you using to connect to the database?
- It's not clear whether the database instance has been started.  Can you connect to the database using `sqlplus / as sysdba` from within the VM?
- What has been written to the `listener.log` file (in `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\log`) since the last reboot?

**EDIT**: I've now been able to come up with a scenario which generates the same error message you got.  It looks to me like the database you're attempting to connect to has not been started up.  The example I present below uses Oracle XE on Linux, but I don't think this makes a significant difference.

First, let us confirm that the database is shut down:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Sat Jul 17 18:16:43 2010

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.
```

It's the text `Connected to an idle instance` that tells us that the database is shut down.

Using `sqlplus / as sysdba` connects us to the database as SYS without needing a password, but it only works on the same machine as the database itself.  In your case, you'd need to run this inside the virtual machine.  SYS has permission to start up and shut down the database, and to connect to it when it is shut down, but normal users don't have these permissions.

Now let us disconnect and try reconnecting as a normal user, one that does not have permission to startup/shutdown the database nor connect to it when it is down:

```
SQL> exit
Disconnected

$ sqlplus -L "user/pw@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)))"

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Sat Jul 17 18:16:47 2010                                                                                                               

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect
descriptor                                                             


SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle.  Exiting SQL*Plus
```

That's the error message you've been getting.

Now, let's start the database up:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Sat Jul 17 18:17:00 2010

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  805306368 bytes
Fixed Size                  1261444 bytes
Variable Size             209715324 bytes
Database Buffers          591396864 bytes
Redo Buffers                2932736 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

Now that the database is up, let's attempt to log in as a normal user:

```
$ sqlplus -L "user/pw@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)))"

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Sat Jul 17 18:17:11 2010

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production

SQL>
```

We're in.

I hadn't seen an ORA-12505 error before because I don't normally connect to an Oracle database by entering the entire connection string on the command line.  This is likely to be similar to how you are attempting to connect to the database.  Usually, I either connect to a local database, or connect to a remote database by using a TNS name (these are listed in the tnsnames.ora file, in `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin`).  In both of these cases you get a different error message if you attempt to connect to a database that has been shut down.

If the above doesn't help you (in particular, if the database has already been started, or you get errors starting up the database), please let us know.

**EDIT 2:** it seems the problems you were having were indeed because the database hadn't been started.  It also appears that your database isn't configured to start up when the service starts.  It is possible to get the database to start up when the service is started, and to shut down when the service is stopped.  To do this, use the Oracle Administration Assistant for Windows, see [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B13831_01/admin.htm#i1008776).

Comment: 1. I used SQL Developer to connect before and after reboot and I also logged in Enterprise Manager web application which dispayed the message I mentioned.

2. I could connect with sqlplus...at least this is how it looks

Comment: It worked but I do not quite get the reason because obviously I don't have much of a clue how Oracle works. I mean the services have a STARTED status why on earth should I execute startup using sqlplus?
I am puzzled here! Thanks a million though!!!

Comment: Anyway I created a batch file executing after logging in Windows which calls 'startup' through sqlplus but still this is a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I Changed Sid Value to `orcl`, it works fine and connection established

Answer (score 2):

You could try this.

In windows go to Administrative Tools->Services  And see scroll down to where it says Oracle[instanceNameHere]  and see if the listener and the service itself are running. You might have to start it. You can also set it to start automatically when you right-click on it and go to properties.

Comment: I already mentioned of checking them but thanks.

'The services are all started and running as far as I checked.'

Answer (score 1):

Give `hibernate.connection.url` as `"jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe"` then you can solve above issue. Because oracle's default SID is "xe" so we should give like this. When I gave like this data has been inserted into DB without any SQL exceptions, it's my real time experience.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me (Windows 7):

```
oradim -shutdown -sid enter_sid_here
oradim -startup -sid enter_sid_here
```

(with `enter_sid_here` replaced by the SID)

Answer (score 1):

1. Start `oracleserviceorcl` service. (From services in Task Manager)
2. Set `ORACLE_SID` variable with `orcl` value. (In environment variables)

Comment: Nice tip parisa